# Inheriting properties from parent pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is there a way to inherit properties from parent pom. 
E.g: I want to replace ${publish.dir} in child pom with the value from parent pom.

**parent pom:**

`<properties> <publish.dir>/tmp/publish</publish.dir> </properties>`

**child pom:**

`<outputDirectory>${publish.dir}/dev</outputDirectory>`

Answer (score 39):

There is no way **not** to inherit properties from a parent POM. Properties defined in a parent are visible in the child.

However. outputDirectory is relatively special part of the POM data model. Inherited properties won't work for that. I'm sorry that it took me so long for the appropriate part of my brain to turn on. I think that you might be out of luck, or might need to specify the output to specific plugins.

Comment: I too think that it should work. What I am trying to do is untar a file in ${publish.dir} whose value should come from parent pom. But, instead maven is creating a new directory in current folder with the name '${publish.dir}'. mvn help:effective-pom|grep publish is also not returning anything.

Comment: Are you sure the parent *is* the parent? Is it correctly listed in the <parent> element? Is the relativePath right?

Comment: **Child pom:**  `<parent> <artifactId>parent</artifactId> <groupId>org</groupId> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> </parent>`  **Parent pom:**  `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> <groupId>org</groupId> <artifactId>parent</artifactId> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> <name>parent</name>`

Comment: Dependencies are getting inherited properly, so I am sure parent pom is getting resolved correctly.